# What happens when one thread is waiting to be executed while another is waiting for input?

Tags: multithreading, cpu

Suppose I have two threads, A and B. A is waiting for input, while B is waiting to be executed. All other CPU cores are busy with CPU-bound tasks.

What will happen to A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A is blocked on I/O.  B is blocked because the operating system chooses to run other processes.

Both are essentially suspended in memory awaiting a time slice.

The operating system offers virtual CPUs to processes that are eligible to run, by way of time slices.  A running processes gets a time slice of a real CPU, by loading the CPU registers and setting loose the CPU.  The OS, can also suspend a process by saving its CPU registers, then turn that same CPU over to another process.

Process A will effectively suspend itself by making the I/O request.  When a blocking I/O request is made the process cannot be allowed to resume until the I/O request is completed.  The operating system makes a note that this process is awaiting some particular I/O operation, and marks the process as "waiting" and thus not eligible for being run.  When the requested I/O completes, the process status is changed to "runnable", which will allow it to resume, and that resumption could be immediate or somewhat delayed.

Whether A resumes before B gets a time slice is dependent upon many factors, some are timing of events, and others are configurations, like process priority.

Comment: Sweet, so it's pretty much like I imagined. A is blocked and so if the OS sees it has more important tasks than A, then it will block A until the OS sees that the I/O request is fulfilled.

Comment: @moonman239:  A is blocked waiting for a result from its I/O request, other threads and their priorities aren’t going to change that.

Comment: Great write-up. I always had  difficulty communicating ideas around thread scheduling because the terminology we use hints at certain false implications. E.g. when we say "Thread A is blocked", it sounds like the thread is doing some active on-going process (in the non-CS sense) that is butting its head up against something and can't proceed. In reality, it merely means that the thread isn't doing anything at all, it just told the Kernel "call me when this is done"

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at this is that the operating system has a run queue and a wait queue.

A, waiting for I/O, is in the wait queue.
B is in the run queue.

The operating system will run each process in the run queue until its time slice expires, change its priority weight, and then run the next thing in the run queue.

When the I/O for A completes, A will be placed in the run queue.  Typically the run queue is ordered by priority weights.  Typically the weights would include how recently a process has run and how much it used of its previous time slice.   Since A has not run in a while, after its I/O has completed it should have top priority and will be the next thing to run in the run queue when it is added, although it probably still has to wait (briefly) for B's time slice to expire.